# R: trimming a variable and adding it to a dataframe

Tags: r, desctools

I am an R beginner. I would like to trim a variable using the Trim function of the package "DescTools". This works fine with:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
 a <- rnorm(40, mean = 0, sd = 1)
 )
a_trim <- Trim(mydata$a, trim = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This creates an object, however, I would like to add it to my dataframe mydata. When I try to do this by

```
mydata$a_trim <- Trim(mydata$a, trim = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

R gives me an error because mydata$a_trim has fewer rows than the dataframe (obviously, since it is a trimmed variable). How can I do this?

Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: To better understand: do you want to set the trimmed rows' `a` value to NA in your dataframe, or do you want to remove those rows?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Edited a dataset to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Trim` isn't suitable for what you want to do. It *removes* extreme values from a vector so that you can pass that vector to something like `mean` or `sd` so that those quantities can be computed without the influence of outliers.

To set extreme values to NA you can use `quantile`.

```
upper_quantile <- quantile(mydata$a, 0.9)
lower_quantile <- quantile(mydata$a, 0.1)

# col a     where a > its 90th percentile    becomes NA
mydata$a[mydata$a > upper_quantile] <- NA
mydata$a[mydata$a < lower_quantile] <- NA
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. One thing that bothers me: After I have converted the top 10% into NA, the lowest 10% are calculated on the updated variable, right? That means, at least to, that if I convert the top 10%, this changes the calculation of the lowest 10% because they are calculated on 90% of the values. Therefore, I need R to it parallely or a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting this post I changed the function `Trim` to return the indices of the trimmed elements as attribute `"trim"`.
Now, you will still get the trimmed vector back, however if you simply want to label the elements to be trimmed, you can do something like:

```
a <- rnorm(40, mean = 0, sd = 1)
a_trim <- Trim(mydata$a, trim = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE)
data.frame(x=a, 
           trim=is.element(seq_len(length(a), attr(a_trim, "trim")))
```

(since DescTools 0.99.18)